# Nano and 3.3V Pro Mini Moves Servo Differently

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, motor, motor-controller, servo

I have a servo which ı want to sweep from 0 to 180 degrees with 25ms delays. The servo is making a door move linearly. Because of that, I can observe how much did the servo actually turn. When I use an arduino nano and a potentiometer to move the servo everything works fine, the door moves through the whole distance. When I move the servo using a for loop like

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 180; i++){
     myservo.write(i);
     delay(25);
}
```

everything works fine, the servo makes the whole sweep. Even when I use this simple code,

```
myservo.write(0);
delay(1000);
myservo.write(180);
delay(1000);
```

everything is fine! But when I use the same methods with a 3.3V Pro Mini, the servo moves less then it moves with nano. the door cant go the whole distance.

I power the servo and arduino from a DC source and they share the common ground.

TLDR:

servo should move a door with 4cm displacement. Using the same code, when arduino nano controls the servo it works fine. When pro mini controls the servo it moves the door about 2.7cm which is not acceptable.

Comment: have you got the correct clock rate set?

Comment: Do you mean choose pro mini 3,3V 8MHz? Yes I did.

Comment: i'm just asking because the pulse length that the servo sees depends on the clock rate used for the pwm.  the guys in the arduino SX will know more about the details.

Comment: So you say the problem could be about the clock rate of 3.3V pro mini being insufficient?

Comment: faster than expected would make the pulses roo short  resulting in not enough movement.

Comment: But ı get full movement with 5V 16Mhz, so ı think thats not it. There are two main differences, one is the clock rate and the other one is the signal voltage level. I tried to use a logic shifter to change the voltage level to 5V and got the same result. Im out of ideas.